# how can an create a dotnet desktop application to access SMS.db on IPhone without Jailbreak?

Tags: c#, iphone

i want to create a desktop application using c#, by which i can access the iphone device and able to read SMS.db to read the SMSs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to read the iPhone's filesystem over USB via the [MobileDevice Library](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=MobileDevice_Library) (not that this will be easy). There's even a [.NET wrapper library](http://code.google.com/p/manzana/) for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible I'm afraid unless you jailbreak and tunnel into the iPhone.

Don't forget to change the default password!

Comment: Odd - what happened to the previous answer?